# Where is XUL 5 SDK for MAC?

Tags: macos, firefox-addon, xulrunner

I am working on Binary component for Firefox 5. 
But I can't find xul sdk here http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/latest-mozilla-beta/ for mac .

From where I can download xul sdk for mac  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They release MAC XUL here 
http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/2011/06/2011-06-09-03-mozilla-beta/